# Android - AndEngine "No Longer Touched" method?

Tags: java, android, methods, andengine

Hi I'm using AndEngine in my Android app. I'm wondering if there is a method that detects when an object (in this case an object of AnalogOnScreenControls) goes from being touched to untouched? I want to set a specific command that executes only when someone lets go of the "analog stick" entity. The controls also use float values to detect what position they're in, so it could also be a method for when the values go from some value other than zero to zero, since the variables are set to zero when the controls are idle. Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag in the TouchEvent that you can check.
Most times I do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent touchEvent, ITouchArea touchArea, float touchAreaLocalX, float touchAreaLocalY) {
    switch(touchEvent.getAction()){
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                    // do stuff when finger moves
                    return true; // don't forget to break, or return true directly if the event was handled
                }
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                    // do stuff, the first time the finger touches the display
                    return true; 
                }
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                    // do stuff when the finger goes up again and ends the touch event (your case)
                    return true; 
                }
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:{
                    // If the event is somehow canceled - e.g. the finger leaves the display
                    return true; 
                }
                default:{
                    // none of the above
                    return false;
                }
    }
}
```

Something like that. If you need more information about the event than theses simple actions, get the MotionEvent with `touchEvent.getMotionEvent()` and check out the additional options there.
BTW: I prefer to use the `return true` statement directly instead of a break here, just to make sure that the touch event won't get used otherwise in the app. But you can change that of course.

hope this helps

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field (global variable) named isTouched and set it initially to false. Then inside onControlChange() you do this:

```
if(pValueX == 0 && pValueY == 0 && isTouched){ //means knob has recently been touched
 isTouched = false; //set to false so that being idle does not come here
 //do your thing here
}
else{
 isTouched = true;
 //do normal stuff here
}
```